Is there a way to disallow some actions from running in the background?
For example, Adobe requests three actions in the background, while one or two of them are clearly not related to the stated software check. How can I selectively allow and disallow some of them?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
